# Filter data by frequency

Tags: r, filter

I'm trying to filter my data to only have the people who show up more than twice. So, in my set I want to go from

```
ID    LUNCH
1     Sandwich
2     Cheese
3     Soup
1     Salad
```

To

```
ID     LUNCH
1      Sandwich
1      Salad
```

Since the only ID that had more than one occurrence was 1

Comment: This is a simple filtering operation. Please read up on how to do it in R.

Comment: @atk8jf If any answers have solved your question, please mark the preferable one as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution:

```
subset(df, ID %in% ID[duplicated(ID)])

#   ID    LUNCH
# 1  1 Sandwich
# 4  1    Salad
```

It's `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(ID %in% ID[duplicated(ID)])
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), LUNCH = c("Sandwich", 
"Cheese", "Soup", "Salad")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), LUNCH = c("Sandwich", 
"Cheese", "Soup", "Salad")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
#Code
df %>% left_join(df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(N=n())) %>%
  filter(N>1) %>% select(-N)

  ID    LUNCH
1  1 Sandwich
2  1    Salad
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

In the `dplyr` package

`newdata <- filter(data, duplicated(data$ID, incomparables = FALSE))`

Comment: I think your output is not correct. Could you check again?

Answer (score -1):

Another dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(LUNCH) %>%
    tally() %>%
    filter(n > 1)
    ungroup()
```